# chmod via cygwin not working properly on windows

Tags: permissions, window, cygwin, chmod

I'm trying to change the permissions of some files on windows to 'rw' only for owner user. As you can see it says that the files are changed to 'rw-------'. When I list the files again nothing is changed.

[image]

Comment: This might be helpful: http://superuser.com/a/408221/219423

Comment: Tried it but nothing. Also, the group is already set to 'Users'

Answer (score 0):

`chmod` is just emulated in Windows for Cygwin and MSys.

The best way to solve the issue is to use `icacls` to change permissions.

The command line could be found in official doc from Microsoft, like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls)

Note that the chmod status in Msys or Cygwin might not be correct. For example, this is what I get in Msys after removing all accesss to "toto.txt"

[image: msys and icacls]